# Obtain User Name Laravel Yajra Datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have this database of user reports with this structure.

[SQL DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXe3c.png)

I need to get the username out of the ids
the ids are in the tables "reportante" and "user_id_afectado"

These data are in the database
users.

Currently I only have the ids of the users I need to have the names as well but they are in another table.

I have this current code.

In ReportesDatatable.php

```json
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Datatables;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use App\Reportes;

class ReportesDatatable
{
    public function ReportesDatatable()
    {
        $reportes = Reportes::get();
        $usernameafectado = User::get();
        
        //dd($usernameafectado[0]->name);       

        return Datatables::of($reportes)
            ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($usernameafectado) {
                return '<span data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="' . $usernameafectado[0]->name . '">' . $usernameafectado->name . '</span>';                
            })      
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($reportes) {
                return '<span data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="' . $reportes->timestamp . '">' . $reportes->timestamp . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($reportes) {
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->reportante) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2"> Ver Reportante</a> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Afectado</a> <a href="' . route('admin.impersonate', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logear como Afectado ' . $reportes->user_id_afectado . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="icon-circle-right2 text-white"></i></a></div>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['role', 'action', 'created_at'])
            ->make(true);

    }
}
```

In my controller

```json
    //Solicitud reportes
        public function verreportesadmin()
    {
        $usuarios = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
        //dd($usuarios);
        $users = Reportes::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
        $count = $users->total();

        return view('admin.verreportesadmin', array(
            'users' => $users,
            'usuarios' => $usuarios,            
            'count' => $count,
        ));
    }
    //Solicitud reportes
```

Currently I get this result where only the ids are shown.

[Image RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g28Ch.png)

EDIT!!!! I FOUND SOLUTION I did it by doing a search with the id but I don't know if this is optimal for the server.

```json
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Datatables;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use App\Reportes;

class ReportesDatatable
{
    public function ReportesDatatable()
    {
        $reportes = Reportes::get();

        return Datatables::of($reportes)
            ->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) {
              $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);              
              return $reportante->name;             
            })      
            ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($reportes) {
              $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);              
              return $nameafectado->name;               
            })      
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($reportes) {
                return '<span data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="' . $reportes->timestamp . '">' . $reportes->timestamp . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($reportes) {
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->reportante) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2"> Ver Reportante</a> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Afectado</a> <a href="' . route('admin.impersonate', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logear como Afectado ' . $reportes->user_id_afectado . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="icon-circle-right2 text-white"></i></a></div>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['role', 'action', 'created_at'])
            ->make(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND SOLUTION I did it by doing a search with the id but I don't know if this is optimal for the server.

```json
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Datatables;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use App\Reportes;

class ReportesDatatable
{
    public function ReportesDatatable()
    {
        $reportes = Reportes::get();

        return Datatables::of($reportes)
            ->editColumn('reportante', function ($reportes) {
              $reportante = User::find($reportes->reportante);              
              return $reportante->name;             
            })      
            ->editColumn('user_id_afectado', function ($reportes) {
              $nameafectado = User::find($reportes->user_id_afectado);              
              return $nameafectado->name;               
            })      
            ->editColumn('created_at', function ($reportes) {
                return '<span data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="' . $reportes->timestamp . '">' . $reportes->timestamp . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($reportes) {
                return '<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified"> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->reportante) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2"> Ver Reportante</a> <a href="' . route('admin.get.editUser', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Afectado</a> <a href="' . route('admin.impersonate', $reportes->user_id_afectado) . '" data-popup="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logear como Afectado ' . $reportes->user_id_afectado . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="icon-circle-right2 text-white"></i></a></div>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['role', 'action', 'created_at'])
            ->make(true);

    }
}
```